# Alternatives from youtube api

Tags: java, android, youtube, open-source

hi guys been spending the last month or so creating a youtube app. its almost ready so i sent out for testing to multiple devices.. works fine on google api enabled devices such as phones. but on amazon devices and none google api devices suchas android boxes and firesticks it simply crashes out on startup..

ive been researching the problem for the last few days and worked out its probably the google api.. especially on amazon devices!

so my question is are there any alternatives to the youtube api. that would allow me to keep my current app and not have to change massive chunks of code to get it to work?

i have seen this on another web page
[github youtube player open source](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/tree/master/core-sample-app/src/main)

and wondered if this could be implemented to use the short codes from the youtube urls ("dFlPARW5IX8") because this is the url ive been storing on my database i dont want to have to change all 200+ to ("https://bla bla.co.uk/dFlPARW5IX8")

any advice would be great cheers

****EDIT*****

Ok so on ive been testing the above code this afternoon and this would be really good for what im after.but i seam to have a problem and was wondering if there is a fix?

so this is the code im using to test the api

```
private String videoId = "6JYIGclVQdw";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(
            new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInitSuccess(
                        final YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {

                    initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(
                            new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onReady() {
                                    initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo((videoId), 0);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }, true);
}
```

when in full screen and press pause it has a menu that doesnt work and the screen seams to be stretched.. its not just in my app it does it if you go to there github and download there test apps from google play they do it as well.

*****EDIT 2*****

so reading through the errors section of the devs github page it seams to be a recent change to youtubes code. this came in to effect in sept this year. 6 days ago he said he was working on a fix. this brilliant news for me.

Comment: I have seen a issue with Youtube API provided by android, that is it doesn't allow us to play video if that device has not Youtube APP installed.

Comment: So for those devices, you can use Youtube webView player. https://github.com/yuliskov/SmartYouTubeTV

Comment: so should i implement a try statement and use both both?

Comment: do you just want to convert string in formate that you could get youtubeId ?

Comment: i dont actually know yet im going to look at the info you have sent through n ill get back to you thanks

Comment: @NehaK ive added to my question. could you take a look please