# YouTube API Key without Developer's Console access in G Suite?

Tags: youtube-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to access the YouTube API. I have access to a G Suite account, but it's for my company and it doesn't have the Developer's Console listed under Apps. Is there any way to access the YouTube API without a Developer's Console app in G Suite, or to forgo G Suite altogether?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily listed in G Suite apps. Here's the link however, you can sign with your company's Google account or your personal one.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, neither my work or personal email have the necessary permissions to allow me to obtain an API key.

Comment: That's weird, I have a YouTube API key with my personal e-mail. I guess it depends on what specific features you want the API to grant you.

Example: I use mine for a Discord Bot to stream audio. I obtained it with no problems and using personal e-mail. What exactly do you need this key for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a personal google account go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ and create a project. Click add APIs, type in YouTube, click the desired API, click enable API, and your done. YouTube API doesn't need approval, a credit card, or permissions. If you are trying to use video media player, consider using Vimeo. There are some alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990229/alternatives-from-youtube-api).